# ASP.NET MVC Dropdown Default value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Please look at my code. I am trying to load the default value for the drop-down. **value** is not accepting from the design. I'm loading data to the combobox from, the account controller, I have added list of items to the **Tempdata** and then in the design I'm assigning the list to the combo box. So here when loading the form I need to set the default value for the combo box drop down list. Please help

This is how I assigning values from the account controller.

```
List<Request_Types> RequestTyleList = db.Request_Types.Where(r => r.Status == true).ToList();
List<SelectListItem> ReqTypeDropDown = RequestTyleList.Select(r => new SelectListItem { Text = r.Request_Type, Value = r.Id.ToString() }).ToList();

TempData["RequestTyleList"] = ReqTypeDropDown;
```

This how I called that `TempData` in the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    List<SelectListItem> ReqTypes = (List<SelectListItem>)TempData.Peek("RequestTyleList");
  
}
```

And this is where I assigning that values to the Combobox in the view

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReqType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
       <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReqType, ReqTypes, new { @class = "js-dropdown" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReqType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

So I when opening the view, I need to assign the default value to the **ReqTypes**

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following parameter to assign default value

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReqType, new SelectList(ReqTypes,"Value","Text","Your_Default_Value"), "Select",new { @class = "js-dropdown" })

Comment: I tried this but it's only added a new item to the drop down. Selected value isn't changing.

Comment: Did you replaced Your_Default_Value?

Comment: If you have tried Your_Default_Value and still it not working. Then you can try binding default value to the ReqType attribute from controller side and pass it to the view.